# Is it possible for a datagrid with a dataprovider to have one column with a different dataprovider?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a datagrid, which gets filled by an ArrayList. I want one column to be filled by another ArrayList. I've tried doing it like this, but that only gets the first three columns filled, not the last one (with the different ArrayList):

```
<s:DataGrid x="10" y="281" width="597" height="204" dataProvider="{arEvents}"
            requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="title" headerText="Column 1" ></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="venue.location.geopoint" headerText="Column 2"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="startDate" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="{arArtistsPerEvent}" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. That would break the very purpose of a datagrid and dataprovider.

One solution would be to parse the second list and put its values in the first one.

```
for(var i:int=0; i<arArtistsPerEvent.length; i++) {
    arEvents.getItemAt(i).artistsPerEvent=arArtistsPerEvent.getItemAt(i);
}
```

and then have the dgColumn like

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="artistsPerEvent" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much for the clear and concise answer!

Comment: of course, you'll have to make  sure that both lists have equal lengths, and that `arEvents.getItemAt(i)` and `arArtistsPerEvent.getItemAt(i)` are both not null

Comment: They will always be the same length, because they come from the same xml-file. I solved it a bit different, by adding it when I parse the XMLList in the array, so I don't have to create the second array ArtistsPerEvent